# Why does this Component does not work when converted to React-Hooks? (confused about this state and destructuring part)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

basically attempting to create an Autocomplete feature for a booking engine the code is in class components want to convert it to a functional component with React Hooks.Have attempted to convert but my code is showing several warnings.can provide any code snippets if needed.
(how do you convert this.state and destructure the this keyword)

import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
    import PropTypes from "prop-types";

```
class AutocompleteClass extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    suggestions: PropTypes.instanceOf(Array)
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    suggestions: []
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      // The active selection's index
      activeSuggestion: 0,
      // The suggestions that match the user's input
      filteredSuggestions: [],
      // Whether or not the suggestion list is shown
      showSuggestions: false,
      // What the user has entered
      userInput: ""
    };
  }

  onChange = e => {
    const { suggestions } = this.props;
    const userInput = e.currentTarget.value;

    // Filter our suggestions that don't contain the user's input
    const filteredSuggestions = suggestions.filter(
      suggestion =>
        suggestion.toLowerCase().indexOf(userInput.toLowerCase()) > -1
    );

    this.setState({
      activeSuggestion: 0,
      filteredSuggestions,
      showSuggestions: true,
      userInput: e.currentTarget.value
    });
  };

  onClick = e => {
    this.setState({
      activeSuggestion: 0,
      filteredSuggestions: [],
      showSuggestions: false,
      userInput: e.currentTarget.innerText
    });
  };

  onKeyDown = e => {
    const { activeSuggestion, filteredSuggestions } = this.state;

    // User pressed the enter key
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      this.setState({
        activeSuggestion: 0,
        showSuggestions: false,
        userInput: filteredSuggestions[activeSuggestion]
      });
    }
    // User pressed the up arrow
    else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
      if (activeSuggestion === 0) {
        return;
      }

      this.setState({ activeSuggestion: activeSuggestion - 1 });
    }
    // User pressed the down arrow
    else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
      if (activeSuggestion - 1 === filteredSuggestions.length) {
        return;
      }

      this.setState({ activeSuggestion: activeSuggestion + 1 });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const {
      onChange,
      onClick,
      onKeyDown,
      state: {
        activeSuggestion,
        filteredSuggestions,
        showSuggestions,
        userInput
      }
    } = this;

    let suggestionsListComponent;

    if (showSuggestions && userInput) {
      if (filteredSuggestions.length) {
        suggestionsListComponent = (
          <ul class="suggestions">
            {filteredSuggestions.map((suggestion, index) => {
              let className;

              // Flag the active suggestion with a class
              if (index === activeSuggestion) {
                className = "suggestion-active";
              }

              return (
                <li className={className} key={suggestion} onClick={onClick}>
                  {suggestion}
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        );
      } else {
        suggestionsListComponent = (
          <div class="no-suggestions">
            <em>No suggestions, you're on your own!</em>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={onChange}
          onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
          value={userInput}
        />
        {suggestionsListComponent}
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default AutocompleteClass;
```

Comment: can you post your code with react-hooks? We help with the errors

Comment: sure one moment

Comment: got the React-hooks code so far... posted as an Answer